# ASP.NET app works in VS2010, but not after publish/deployment

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a problem that I can't resolve, and am hoping someone might have some insight.  I apologize in advance if this question seems vague, but it's difficult to describe.  I'll do the best I can with it.  Please feel free to ask clarification questions.

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 app that I inherited and am trying to retrofit for our use.  When I build and run it in VS2010 (basically, just hitting F5), it works with no problem.

HOWEVER . . .  I tried to create and publish a package with it (since I need to know if it works after deployment), and this is where I run into problems.

Specifically, the problem occurs in an AJAX call that tries to save data to a back-end SQL database.  The script hits a "return false" in the JavaScript (to keep the front-end form from submitting), and it clocks . . .  and clocks . . .  and clocks . . .  In other words, it hangs up.  It does not give me any error messages or codes.  It *does* allow me to click the [x] to get out of the processing message box, but as a result, my data does not save.  Again, this ONLY happens in the published/deployed app.  This DOES NOT HAPPEN when I run it in VS2010.

I've already determined that the back-end C# code is *not* the culprit (there are other functions on other pages that call the same code, and they work fine).  I tried running a trace, and it seems like it's hanging on the following piece of code in jquery-1.4.2.min.js.

```
return typeof c!=="undefined"&&!c.event.triggered?c.event.handle.apply(o.elem,arguments):w
```

(Note: this is in line 49 of the jquery-1.4.2.min.js file.  Again, apologies if this seems vague.)

It almost seems like the code is caught in an infinite loop.  I can't figure out what's causing it.  Again, this is only after deployment.  The VS2010 build (pre-deployment) runs fine.

I figure there's a setting in the environment I need to check, but I don't know where to look.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Not sure how helpful or relevant this is, but at the very least, I'm posting this for my own reference: http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/59/locally-publishing-a-vs2010-asp.net-web-application-using-msbuild

Comment: Well, I tried the manual build.  No dice.  The process is still hanging.  I'm still looking for help on this.  Anyone???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I figured it out.  Turns out that the service being called by the AJAX was throwing a 500 error without my realizing it.

If that ends up being the answer, I'll mark this as such.

**Edit:** That turned out to be the answer.  I found an environment-specific attribute in the code that was causing the 500 error.  After I rewrote the code and published the application, it worked with no problem.